# Wordpress Custom Theme: Plugins Won't Load or Display Only Code

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress-theming, display

This is my first attempt at creating a theme purely from scratch. Before this I just used underscores_me and made most of my changes to style.css and left the majority of PHP alone, because I'm a novice with it.

My issue is that plugins are not working. None of the ones I have installed work. At this point I have been trying plugins that create an event calendar, but I'm assuming that any and all plugins will have issues. In the areas that are meant to display the calendar, there are two things I'm seeing. Plugin-generated pages show nothing at all (aside from the theme visuals) and plugins that are inserted into an admin-created page display plugin-generated code.

I am using WampServer. I have wp_footer(); and wp_head(); in the correct places. My functions.php file was created from the example found at https://scanwp.net/blog/create-a-wordpress-starter-theme-from-scratch/ and the only adjustment I have made to it so far is to remove the fontawesome line of code.

My index.php file looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<h1><?php echo "&#9755&nbsp;"; ?><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        // Display post content
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And my page.php file looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <h1><?php echo "&#9755&nbsp;"; ?><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?= get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID) ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that in your displayed files, there are no functions that recall objects that will later show the page content.

Then, in your index.php file there is an error, besides what was said above, because you're calling the_title () (function) that extrapolates the title of a post or page via the post object, which in this case should be extracted within the while loop contained within the if condition.

Then try editing the files as follows.

index.php

```
<?php


get_header(); ?>


<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php if( is_singular() ) : ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h1>No posts to display</h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and page.php

```
<?php


get_header(); ?>



<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, within the wordpress codex you will find all the guides well written on any type of function, look no further.

source: https://codex.wordpress.org/